# WebdriverAgent error on using driver.keys() on iOS device

Tags: ios, appium, webdriver-io, xcuitest

I am writing automation test for mobile using Appium + WebdriverIO
I need to enter a value from the keyboard using `driver.keys()`

On Android device it works . On iOS device I have got next error:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Key Down action '1' must have a closing Key Up successor in '{
    type = keyDown;
    value = 1;
}'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Key Down action '1' must have a closing Key Up successor in '{
    type = keyDown;
    value = 1;
```

I was searching for a possible fix in Google but did not find it.
Please, help with it.